# finding distinct categories

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT PRODUCTS.p_id, model, price, CATEGORIES.category
FROM PRODUCTS, CATEGORIES
WHERE PRODUCTS.subcat_id = CATEGORIES.category_id
AND PRODUCTS.model LIKE  '%$qtitle%'";
```

I want to select the distinct values from the category field.

Can someone give me advice?

Right now there are repeating values. I want only the distinct values once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a GROUP BY CATEGORY.category clause at the end of your sql statement.

Comment: thank you. but i still have a problem. this is it: im performing a search from a form, and it prints a list of products and their categorys. But i want to list all of the products whichs contains the like %qtitle% but i only want to list the category name once. I DONT THINK IT IS POSSIBLE?

Answer (score 0):

If you want distinct category, you have to select only category and use the distinct keyword.

```
select distinct categories.category
from....
```

By its very nature, you can't expect a result like

```
1, modelA, $50, CategoryX
2, mode55D, $57, 
3, model8D, $60, 
4, mode3lA, $80, 
5, mode2A, $55,
```

It must repeat that value.

Comment: Thanks. I believe I will have to re design my tables. Basically I want to display the categories that relate to the search results only once.

Comment: Outside a reporting engine (or excel) or something external to a raw sql query, that can't happen.